# What are the restrictions of xsd:anySimpleType on xsd:anyType, and where are they enumerated?

Tags: xml, xsd

An element of type `anyType` is permitted to have any attributes and any value-space content, including subelements. Where are the restrictions stipulated for `anySimpleType`? I am especially interested in the restriction that only specified (by a given XSD document) attributes are permitted.

Assuming `libxml2`'s schema validation is faithful to the spec, the following shows at least one restriction of `anySimpleType`:

`foo.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Bar" type="xs:anyType" />
        <xs:element name="Baz" type="xs:anySimpleType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

`foo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Foo>
  <Bar abc="xyz" />
  <Baz abc="xyz" />
</Foo>
```

Validation:

```
$ xmllint --noout foo.xml --schema foo.xsd 
foo.xml:5: element Baz: Schemas validity error : Element 'Baz', attribute 'abc': The attribute 'abc' is not allowed.
foo.xml fails to validate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anySimpleType` is an abstract base simple type.   It is completely unrestricted.

http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_anySimpleType.html

If you want to specify that only a list of attributes are allowed, that is the job of the "complex types", such as `simpleType`.  (Great naming for these, huh?  =/)

http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_simpleType.html

[Edit re your example]:

Ah, ok I see what you are asking now.

In XSD "simple" types categorically, rather than via restriction, cannot have attributes.  (Some parsers allow some default attributes, such as {'type','nil', 'schemaLocation', 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation'} in NS http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance; these are useful for extension of this base type.)   They are intended to be atomic, literal, etc - anything that can be a /value/ of an attribute in XML.

`anySimpleType` is exactly what the name implies - a completely unrestricted simple type.  It cannot take attribute 'abc', because simple types cannot have attributes - they are attribute values.   If you want an element to accept a list of attributes, as I say above that is the job of "complex" types, not "simple" types.

This is covered in the specification:  https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Type_Derivation

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I just updated the question with a validation failure example.

Answer (score 3):

An **[`xsd:anyType`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#key-urType)** can be complex or simple ([**`xsd:anySimpleType`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-anySimpleType)).  Only complex types can have attributes.

The relationship between `xsd:anyType` and `xsd:anySimpleType` (and all complex types) can be clearly seen in the diagram in W3C's XSD Recommendation: [3 Built-in datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes):

[image]